# Is there a way to determine if a string exists in a field (in a table), then get the value in another field for that same record?

Tags: vba, ms-access

DCount does not work for this, as it only determine if an instance exists.  Any ideas?  I assume this is a very simple task, but am having trouble finding something suitable using google :-(

Answer (score 1):

DLookup will give you the result of any expression on a source of data (table/query) for the first record (row of data) that matches an optional criteria, including the value on a different column.

> dim foundValue AS Variant
>
> foundValue = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[tableOrQueryName]", "[ColumnToCheckAgainst] = 'some string' ")

It returns whatever value it finds in column [ColumnName] (or feel free to use any expression you would use in a SELECT statement) of the first row in table/query [tableOrQueryName] that matches the criteria specified as the third argument (anything you can put in a WHERE clause is allowed here, just remember you cannot use double quotes to quote string values - you escape those with another double-quote inside a string literal, but you don't need the single quotes if you specify numbers for example).

The criteria argument you can omit (it's optional and it defaults to no condition).

Set the result to a Variant variable since it may very well be a NULL (also when criteria not met for any record).

The example above will work similarly to the query "SELECT TOP 1 [ColumnName] FROM [tableOrQueryName] WHERE [ColumnToCheckAgainst] = 'some string';".

Documentation for DLookup:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

Another way would be to use a Recordset object.